# Add database to Visual studio 2015 - ODBC connection

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015, odbc

I have been trying to connect my ODBC database to a new program I was making.

Steps I am going to get there:

Tools
Connect to Database
Microsoft ODBC Data Source ( Data provider: .Net Framework Data Provider For ODBC)
Continue:

In Data source Specification: 
I am trying to use a system Data Name: When I select one of the sources from the drop down list. As soon as I select it, it fades out and goes blank as if I have not selected anything.

Comment: Maybe try using a connection string to the data source instead? If I have a data source with the name "DataSource" the connection string would be "Dsn=DataSource". I cannot reproduce the issue, myself. If that doesn't work I would try to recreate the data source, as I have encountered some issues where an ODBC data source was corrupted or something similar that made it inaccessible.

Comment: Another option is to use the Server Explorer (View:Server Explorer) to create a Data Connection. It most likely uses the same internal method/ dialog, though, so it will probably run into the same issue.

Comment: I tried using server explorer, when I try to select the server the wizard just closes. If I try selecting a database it just blacks out so that I cannot select anything in that box.  I haven't tried the manual way yet, was just attempting to see if I can get it in the wizard as I don't know all the table names I need to go through typing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If restarting VS/ rebooting does not clear up the issue it may have to do with a 64-bit ODBC connection and 32-bit VS.

Comment: How do I check which bit version I have for VS ? or is it defaulted at 32

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no 64-bit version, as of yet.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll see if I can go back to an older version of visual studio and see if the same results happen or not.